# Sqlite cannot insert data when database insider src folder

Tags: java, sqlite

I spend like 5 hour re-writing all methods cause thought i make mistake while inserting data into DB **BUT** i noticed everything is fine when i got database outside src folder.

This is my code

public class DataBaseModel {

```
    public static final String DRIVER = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
//  public static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlite::resource:sqlite/databse.db"; // insider src/sqlite
    public static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlite:database.db"; 

private Connection conn=null;
private Statement stat=null;

public DataBaseModel() {
    try {
        Class.forName(DataBaseModel.DRIVER);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("NO JDBC DRIVER");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
        stat = conn.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Connection problem");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    createTables();
}
```

When i got my project setup like that:

`public static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlite:database.db";`

everythin work fine:

1. creating records
2. display records form db
3. creating tables

But when i change to

`public static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlite::resource:sqlite/databse.db";`

there is an error

```
Connection problem java.sql.SQLException: resource sqlite/database.db not found: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: sqlite/database.db
```

I get rid of error unconsciously by copping database to src/sqlite thats why i was unable to see any error for all that time ...

Any idea what cause problem when database.db is inside src/sqlite?

I explained as much as i can.

Thx for help

Comment: So to put a finer point on your folder structure, you have  a `src/` and a `resources/` folder, and you want your database to live inside of your `resources/` folder, right?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxqsep0l38d5vu8/Zrzut%20ekranu%202016-11-01%2020.16.33.png?dl=0 i've got something like that